# Can't set Loaded Layer Name to input name in Load Layer into Project using QGIS Model Designer

Tags: qgis, layers, style, qgis-modeler

I am designing a simple model to automate the loading and styling of new layers in a QGIS project. The idea is to use "Set layer style" to apply style settings from a QML file then load the layer into the project. I cannot, however, figure out how to add the layer to the project using layer's filename. The only thing that works is setting a static name ("Value") in "Loaded Layer Name", but this would be the same for every layer loaded. I've tried using a Pre-Calculated Value with the name of the input (@Input_vector), but this does not work.

This seems to be related to issues recalling the variables associated with inputs, but I can't find any workable solution.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's a polyline shapefile layer

Comment: No, that's why I'm using "Load layer into project"